# Liferay6.0:Rendering DL portlet URL after clicking on custom TreeView portlet

Tags: liferay-6, ztree

I am using 6.0.6 CE to develop a requirement where a page has two portlets. One at left and other at right hand side.
1. Custom portlet which loads list of folders in a Tree structure for a given community. Here I am using jQuery zTree where doView get me the list of folders in JSON array.
http://www.ztree.me/v3/demo.php#_102

2. Document Library portlet

Every node folder has URL of document library such as:
http://yourdomain.com/web/oracle/home/-/document_library/view/11614

When I click any of it, reloads the entire page and DL portlet shows children of the given folder id 11614.
But because of this left hand side tree structure gets collapsed.

I wanted to retain the user selection on left side. For this I just thought of rendering only document library portlet on clicking on the folder but I am not able to achieve it thru any of the IPC.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am following this approach:
During page load I am getting the folderId from URL and in doView(), I am passing it as renderRequest param.
    long selectedFolderId = 0;

```
String friendlyUrlValue = PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(renderRequest);

String[] urlArray = friendlyUrlValue.split("/");
String secondLastword = urlArray[urlArray.length - 2];
if (urlArray.length > 0) {
    if (secondLastword.equalsIgnoreCase("view")) {
        selectedFolderId = Long.valueOf(urlArray[urlArray.length - 1]);
    }
}


JSONObject jSONObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
createJson(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, jSONObject, renderRequest, fridendlyUrl);

if(selectedFolderId>0){
    renderRequest.setAttribute("selectedFId", String.valueOf(selectedFolderId));
}
```

Refer this post https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47300920

There should be another approach to achieve reloading of only document Library portlet instead of entire page reload. Please let me know if there is any better approach for this.